# setting command line quoted params

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I need to launch command prompt from my application and set arguments for it.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "\"C:\Program Files\My Program\program.exe\" \"C:\Program Files\My Program\Program2.exe\"");
```

The line abowe would be good for me, but he problem is quotes. To have quotes in cmd i need to escape them, but when i escape them, i get escape symbols `\` in my command, so it doesnt work.
Anybody has an idea, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string SystemDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
```

With quoutes:

```
const string SystemDirectory = @"""C:\Windows\System32""";
```

Comment: And how exactly this should help? both cmd parameters have spaces in paths, so they have to be quoted if i use `@"path"` i get parameters without qoutes and that does not work.

Comment: @JNM, try using this (single line): `const string CommandLine = @"""C:\Windows\System32\program.exe"" ""C:\input.txt""";`

Comment: I tried, but when i use `""` i get `\"` in command line instead of `"`

Comment: [This is how it works for me.](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/clipboard02du.png/)
Is there something wrong?

Comment: This is my code: `string command = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe"" ""C:\temp\serviceFiles\test.dbf"" /EXPORT:C:\temp\serviceFiles\test.csv /SEP  ";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", command);` and the command given to command line is `\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DBF Viewer 2000\\dbview.exe\" \"C:\\temp\\serviceFiles\\test.dbf\" /EXPORT:C:\\temp\\serviceFiles\\test.csv /SEP  ` which is wrong. intead of `\"` it should have only `"`

Comment: Something magical happend and this solution started working:  

    `System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DBF_VIEWER_PATH") + "\" \"" + filePath + "\" /EXPORT:\"" + newFilePath + "\" /SEP   ";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();`

Comment: @JNM, your code (right after my last message) works as designed. I believe you are watching the string variable value using Autos or Locals panel. But [try using Text Visualizer](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/clipboard03x.png/). Cheers.

Comment: @JNM, I see you are concatenating the arguments string. I suppose, `string.Format` would be better.

Comment: Ok, now i use Text Visualizer. I see good cmd params.When i copy them to comman line and execute - everything works. When i launch cmd from my program, i can see cmd open, but nothing happens.

Comment: What about this?
`string applicationPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBF Viewer 2000\dbview.exe";
string command = @"""C:\temp\serviceFiles\test.dbf"" /EXPORT:C:\temp\serviceFiles\test.csv /SEP";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(applicationPath, command);`

Comment: Now i have another problem... It generates good parameters, starts cmd but does nothing.

Comment: @JNM, another problem -> another question? Finished with this question? :)

Comment: Yes. Everything ok now with command line arguments. I asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113579/command-line-with-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe",
              "\"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\program.exe\" " +
              "\"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\Program2.exe\"");
```

Note the double backslashes in the path.

An alternative would be to use a verbatim string (Note the @ sign in front of the string). In that case you need to escape the quotes as two quotes:

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe",
              @"""C:\Program Files\My Program\program.exe"" " +
              @"""C:\Program Files\My Program\Program2.exe""");
```

Comment: You can't jump lines like this in the middle of a string. It's allowed only for verbatim strings, but it'll insert a new line into the string, which is not expected here. Maybe a string.Format() would be more appropriate here?

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. Instead of `""` i get `\"` ant in command line thar does not work.