# Command line with parameters

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

i have this code:

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FILE_SAVE_PATH") + fileName;
string newFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FILE_SAVE_PATH") + fileName.Replace(".dbf", ".csv");
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FILE_SAVE_PATH");
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" /EXPORT:{2} /SEPTAB", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DBF_VIEWER_PATH"), filePath, newFilePath);
try
{
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch{}
```

The problem is, that it starts command line, and does nothing. It seems that it does not pass arguments to command line (command line is empty). Anybody has an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: You are hiding any exceptions, so you can't really know what error is happening... Take that try/catch away and DEBUG.

Comment: @JIM: did that EXE process was written by you? Are you able to change it ?

Comment: @Pedro: I tried debugging, but there is no bug, no exception.

Comment: @Tigran: None of exe files here is mine. I can't change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem. It was in me. I was trying to launch command line and give parameters to it, so it would launch another program with parameters. Isn't that stupid?
Now i launch the program i need with parameters and it works perfectly:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FILE_SAVE_PATH");
startInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DBF_VIEWER_PATH");
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" /EXPORT:{1} /SEPTAB", filePath, newFilePath);
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: I will, but system does not allow me to do that. I have to wait until tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add `/c` (`Carries out command and then terminates`) argument to cmd.exe:

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c \"{0}\" \"{1}\" /EXPORT:{2} /SEPTAB", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DBF_VIEWER_PATH"), filePath, newFilePath);
```

EDIT: As Pedro noted, you really should avoid `catch{}` as it will hide any thrown exception.

Comment: I removed `try{} catch{}` and there is no exception. With `/c` it starts comman line and closes it, but does not execute any command. If i use Text Visualizer and paste arguments to command line, it sais that `/c` is not recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Use catch like this:

```
try
{
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     Console.Writeline(ex.ToString());
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

so the occured exception will be displayed and will give you crucial informations about what is wrong.